# Assign key name to the value and convert to it to the single array

Tags: angular

I have nested Array Format in which there is no name assigned to the values, the format is shown below:

```js
response.data: [{
  2018: [{
    December: [{
      complaintRaised: 8
      totalClosed: 0
      totalPending: 8
      totalResolved: 0
    }]
  }],
  2019: [{
    January: [{
      complaintRaised: 2
      totalClosed: 0
      totalPending: 2
      totalResolved: 0
    }]
  }]
}]
```

which I need to convert it into a single array with key names assign to the values.

```js
response.data: [{
    key: "2019"
    complaintRaised: 8
    totalClosed: 0
    totalPending: 8
    totalResolved: 0
    year: "2018-December"
  },
  {
    key: "2018"
    complaintRaised: 2
    totalClosed: 0
    totalPending: 2
    totalResolved: 0
    year: "2019-January"
  }
]
```

Comment: Your json seems invalid please check again

Comment: Please try the question yourself. Make your question more clear. For example, why is `complaintRaised: 1`!

Comment: The values in the expected output don't match those in the input, (how) should they be calculated?

Comment: no, you don't have to calculate, the array format is correct that's how the format I am receiving from the backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to map the object key from the first array as a property of each flattened element, using pure javascript the code below may work for you.

Please, tell me if it solves your problem.

```js
const x = [{
  2018: [{
    December: [{
      complaintRaised: 8,
      totalClosed: 0,
      totalPending: 8,
      totalResolved: 0
    }]
  }],
  2019: [{
    January: [{
      complaintRaised: 2,
      totalClosed: 0,
      totalPending: 2,
      totalResolved: 0
    }]
  }]
}];

const result = Object.entries(x[0]).map((e) => {
 return Object.assign(
        {}, 
        Object.values(e[1][0])[0][0], 
        { key: e[0], year: e[0] + '-' + Object.keys(e[1][0])[0] }
    );
})


console.log(result);
```